# Amazon Web Services (AWS) S3 Java create a sub directory (object)

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am familiar with [AWS Java SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/), I also tried to browse the corresponding [Javadoc](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/), but I could not realize how do I create a sub directory, i.e., a directory object within a bucket, and how do I upload files to it.

Assume `bucketName` and `dirName` correspond to already existing bucket (with public permission) and a new (object) directory which needs to be created within the bucket (i.e. bucketName/dirName/)

I have tried the following:

```
AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client(
    new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY));
s3.createBucket(bucketName + "/" + dirName); //throws exception
```

which throws an exception on the second line.

A short snippet which creates a sub-directory and uploads files to it will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There are no "sub-directories" in S3. There are buckets and there are keys within buckets.

You can emulate traditional directories by using prefix searches. For example, you can store the following keys in a bucket:

```
foo/bar1
foo/bar2
foo/bar3
blah/baz1
blah/baz2
```

and then do a prefix search for `foo/` and you will get back:

```
foo/bar1
foo/bar2
foo/bar3
```

See [`AmazonS3.listObjects`](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#listObjects%28com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsRequest%29) for more details.

---

**Update:** Assuming you already have an existing bucket, the key under that bucket would contain the `/`:

```
s3.putObject("someBucket", "foo/bar1", file1);
s3.putObject("someBucket", "foo/bar2", file2);
...
```

Then you can list all keys starting with `foo/`:

```
ObjectListing listing = s3.listObjects("someBucket", "foo/");
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, could please provide a short snippet code? Since as you see in my post, I have tried to create something like `foo/bar` but it throws an exception.

Answer (score 35):

S3 doesn't see directories in the traditional way we do this on our operating systems. 
Here is how you can create a directory:

```
public static void createFolder(String bucketName, String folderName, AmazonS3 client) {
    // create meta-data for your folder and set content-length to 0
    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    metadata.setContentLength(0);

    // create empty content
    InputStream emptyContent = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]);

    // create a PutObjectRequest passing the folder name suffixed by /
    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName,
                folderName + SUFFIX, emptyContent, metadata);

    // send request to S3 to create folder
    client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
}
```

As casablanca already said you can upload files to directories like this:

```
s3.putObject("someBucket", "foo/bar1", file1);
```

Read the whole tutorial [here](http://javatutorial.net/java-s3-example) for details, and the most important thing is you will find info how to delete the directories.

Answer (score 6):

In newer versions of the SDK, you can do something like this (no need to create empty InputStream) to create an empty folder:

```
String key = parentKey + newFolderName;
if (!StringUtils.endsWith(key, "/")) {
    key += "/";
}

PutObjectRequest putRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
        .bucket(parent.getBucket())
        .key(key)
        .acl("public-read")
        .build();
s3Client.putObject(putRequest, RequestBody.empty());
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this answer here just in case someone stumbles upon this. I have been using *aws sdk version - 1.11.875* and the following successfully created a folder for me when trying to upload a file into S3 bucket. I did not have to explicitly create the folder as mentioned in the earlier answer.

```
private void uploadFileToS3Bucket(final String bucketName, final File file) {
    final String fileName = "parent/child/" + file.getName();
    final PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, file);
    amazonS3.putObject(putObjectRequest);
}
```

This will create the parent and parent/child folders in the specified S3 bucket and upload the file into child folder.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I used spring boot and file uploaded according to Multipart mechanism. I wanted to save my images inside the *photos* folder in my aws s3 bucket. My need is save like this photos/mypic.jpg

----controller class method----

```
@PostMapping("/uploadFile")
    public String uploadFile(@RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        return this.amazonClient.uploadFile(file);
}
```

----service class (Implementation of controller)----

```
 public String uploadFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
    
            try {
                File file = convertMultiPartToFile(multipartFile);
                String fileName = "photoes/"+generateFileName(multipartFile);  //here give any folder name you want
                uploadFileTos3bucket(fileName, file);
            } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
                logger.info("Caught an AmazonServiceException from GET requests, rejected reasons:");
            }
            return fileName;
        }
```

*The point is concatenate the folder name you want as prefix of the fileName*

additionally I will show you how to delete folder. The point is give the folder name as the keyName(key name is uploaded object name in the s3 bucket.). I will show code snippet also.

----controller class method----

```
@DeleteMapping("/deleteFile")
    public String deleteFile(@RequestPart(value = "keyName") String keyName) {
        return this.amazonClient.deleteFile(keyName);
    }
```

----service class (Implementation of controller)----

```
 public String deleteFile(String keyName){
        try {
            s3client.deleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName));
        } catch (SdkClientException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "deleted file successfully!";
    }
```

for delete photos folder that we created , call method like this. `deleteFile("photos/")`
*important:- / is mandatory*

Answer (score -2):

if You want to create folder then you need to use put command using following keys to create *folder1* in:

in root of bucket -> folder1/folder1_$folder$

in path folder2/folder3/ -> folder2/folder3/folder1/folder1_$folder$

It is always all_previous_folders/folderName/folderName_$folder$