# Placing file inside folder of S3 bucket

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp, spring-integration-aws

have a spring boot application, where I am tring to place a file inside folder of S3 target bucket. target-bucket/targetsystem-folder/file.csv

The targetsystem-folder name will differ for each file which will be retrived from yml configuration file.

The targetsystem-folder have to created via code if the folder doesnot exit and file should be placed under the folder

As I know, there is no folder concept in S3 bucket and all are stored as objects.

Have read in some documents like to place the file under folder, have to give the key-expression like targetsystem-folder/file.csv and bucket = target-bucket.
But it doesnot work out.Would like to achieve this using spring-integration-aws without using aws-sdk directly

```
    <int-aws:s3-outbound-channel-adapter id="filesS3Mover"
        channel="filesS3MoverChannel"
        transfer-manager="transferManager"
        bucket="${aws.s3.target.bucket}"
        key-expression="headers.targetsystem-folder/headers.file_name"
        command="UPLOAD">
</int-aws:s3-outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Can anyone guide on this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem that the SpEL in the `key-expression` is wrong. Just try to start from the regular Java code and imagine how you would like to build such a value. Then you'll figure out that you are missing concatenation operation in your expression:

```
 key-expression="headers.targetsystem-folder + '/' + headers.file_name"
```

Also, please, in the future provide more info about error. In most cases the stack trace is fully helpful.

Comment: It works. As suggested , Will provide stack trace in future questions.

Answer (score 0):

In the project that I was working before, I just used the java aws sdk provided. Then in my implementation, I did something like this

```
private void uploadFileTos3bucket(String fileName, File file) {
    s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("target-bucket", "/targetsystem-folder/"+fileName, file)
            .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
}
```

I didn't create anymore configuration. It automatically creates `/targetsystem-folder` inside the bucket(then put the file inside of it), if it's not existing, else, put the file inside.

---

You can take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11491437/6952155) as reference, for further explanation of the subject.

> There are no "sub-directories" in S3. There are buckets and there are
>   keys within buckets.
>
> You can emulate traditional directories by using prefix searches. For
>   example, you can store the following keys in a bucket:

```
foo/bar1
foo/bar2
foo/bar3
blah/baz1
blah/baz2
```

Comment: Thank for the reply. Would like to know this can be achieved using spring -integration -aws itself using outbound adapter without using aws-sdk directly

Comment: Sorry for not understanding your question. Hope you find an answer soon.

Comment: This answer definitely shows what Spring Integration does in its `S3MessageHandler`, but doesn't give any clues for the original request about Spring Integration AWS extension. Please, see my answer.

Comment: yeah, I misundestood his question as I haven't used `spring-integration-aws` before. I am so sorry for that. Thank you for your answer as I may need it too in the future. +1